# Conversion of SQL Row values into Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result from SQL table, Need to split values of one column into another two new columns.

Column name "attributename" will always have two values "CompletedDate" and "CompletedExitDate". With corresponding timestamp value in column name "endvalue".

We need to Display "CompletedDate" "CompletedExitDate" as two different new column, with corresponding Timestamp values from "endvalue".

Actual table output:

```
transactionid   objectid       attributeid transactiondate         username         attributename       endvalue
42120           8291            1062        03/25/19  2:28:05 PM    JOHN            CompletedDate       3/25/2019 2:28:06 PM
41911           8291            1096        03/22/19  3:18:59 PM    WF_SERVICE      CompletedExitDate   3/22/2019 3:18:59 PM
41910           8291            1062        03/22/19  3:10:58 PM    JOHN            CompletedDate       3/22/2019 3:10:59 PM
41669           8291            1096        03/21/19  2:57:10 PM    WF_SERVICE      CompletedExitDate   3/21/2019 2:57:10 PM
41661           8291            1062        03/21/19  2:12:51 PM    JOHN            CompletedDate       3/21/2019 2:12:52 PM
```

Expected Output from the table:

```
transactionid   objectid    attributeid transactiondate   username  CompletedDate       CompletedExitDate
42120           8291        1062        3/25/19 2:28 PM   JOHN       3/25/19 2:28 PM    Null
41910           8291        1062        3/22/19 3:10 PM   JOHN       3/22/19 3:10 PM    3/22/19 3:18 PM
41661           8291        1062        3/21/19 2:12 PM   JOHN       3/21/19 2:12 PM    3/21/19 2:57 PM
```

Query Tried 1 :

```
SELECT
    A.[objectid], 
    max(case when attributename = 'CompletedDate'  then A.[endvalue] end) AS CompletedDate,
    max(case when attributename = 'CompletedExitDate'  then A.[endvalue] end) AS CompletedExitDate
FROM
    RMOBJECTHISTORY A join rmattribute B on A.attributeid= B.attributeid 
    where (A.[objectid]=8291 and  (B.attributename='CompletedDate' and A.[endvalue] <> '')) or (A.[objectid]=8291 and (B.attributename='CompletedExitDate' and A.[endvalue] <> '')) 
GROUP BY
   A.[objectid],transactiondate
ORDER BY
    transactiondate desc ;
```

Output of the Query Tried 1 :

```
objectid    CompletedDate       CompletedExitDate
8291        3/25/19 2:28 PM     NULL
8291        NULL                3/22/19 3:18 PM
8291        3/22/19 3:10 PM     NULL
8291        NULL                3/21/19 2:57 PM
8291        3/21/19 2:12 PM     NULL
```

Query Tried 2 :

```
SELECT
    A.[objectid], transactionid,attributeid,
    max(case when attributename = 'CompletedDate'  then A.[endvalue] end) AS CompletedDate,
    max(case when attributename = 'CompletedExitDate'  then A.[endvalue] end) AS CompletedExitDate FROM
    RMOBJECTHISTORY A join rmattribute B on A.attributeid= B.attributeid 
    where (A.[objectid]=8291 and  (B.attributename='CompletedDate' and A.[endvalue] <> '')) or (A.[objectid]=8291 and (B.attributename='CompletedExitDate' and A.[endvalue] <> ''))  GROUP BY    A.[objectid],transactionid,attributeid
```

Output of Query 2 :

```
objectid    transactionid   attributeid CompletedDate       CompletedExitDate
8291        41661           1062        3/21/19 2:12 PM     NULL
8291        41910           1062        3/22/19 3:10 PM     NULL
8291        42120           1062        3/25/19 2:28 PM     NULL
8291        41669           1096        NULL                3/21/19 2:57 PM
8291        41911           1096        NULL                3/21/19 2:57 PM
```

Issue is, for every "CompletedDate" there is corresponding "CompletedExitDate" which is listed in "endvalue" of initial query.When we are trying to convert into new columns it goes to new row with value "NULL".

We need below output finally :

```
CompletedDate      CompletedExitDate
3/21/19 2:12 PM    3/21/19 2:57 PM
3/22/19 3:10 PM    3/21/19 2:57 PM
3/25/19 2:28 PM    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `transactiondate` from group by

```
SELECT
    A.[objectid], 
    max(case when attributename = 'CompletedDate'  then A.[endvalue] end) AS CompletedDate,
    max(case when attributename = 'CompletedExitDate'  then A.[endvalue] end) AS CompletedExitDate
FROM
    RMOBJECTHISTORY A join rmattribute B on A.attributeid= B.attributeid 
    where (A.[objectid]=8291 and  (B.attributename='CompletedDate' and A.[endvalue] <> '')) or (A.[objectid]=8291 and (B.attributename='CompletedExitDate' and A.[endvalue] <> '')) 
GROUP BY
   A.[objectid]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to `transactionid,attributeid` into selection and group by

```
SELECT
    A.[objectid], transactionid,A.attributeid,
    max(case when attributename = 'CompletedDate'  then A.[endvalue] end) AS CompletedDate,
    max(case when attributename = 'CompletedExitDate'  then A.[endvalue] end) AS CompletedExitDate
FROM
    RMOBJECTHISTORY A join rmattribute B on A.attributeid= B.attributeid 
    where (A.[objectid]=8291 and  (B.attributename='CompletedDate' and A.[endvalue] <> '')) or (A.[objectid]=8291 and (B.attributename='CompletedExitDate' and A.[endvalue] <> '')) 
GROUP BY
   A.[objectid],transactionid,A.attributeid
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul, Thanks for the reply.   we tried your updated query, but we are getting null values. Please refer updated question.

Comment: Share your original table values in your question

Comment: Please refer Actual table output and and Expected table Output